# How to see the functions and scripts being called when playing game

Tags: debugging, unity-game-engine, reverse-engineering

I am new to Unity and trying to understand a pretty complex Unity project.
I am trying to reverse engineer here.

While playing the game in Unity, how do I see the functions and scripts being called while tapping on game objects.
Is there a way to do this without touching the code.

In Xcode, one can see what is happening during runtime in a tab below. 
Pretty difficult to figure out same thing in Unity. :(

Please help

Answer (score 0):

There is no such way, you have to touch the code.

Comment: why dont you start tracing from the awake function and put some debug, you will easily understand the way the code is going through.